# UITalbeView need to delete row that might be reordering

Tags: swift, uitableview

No, my code is not crashing by just deleting content, or reordering content, that works fine.

The issue is, the content is connected to a pusher service and it might need to delete a row at any point, even while reordering. I have been looking around for some time and I haven't found a way to:

- Cancel the reordering of the cell when delete is needed (it goes
  blank / clear).
- Avoid any actions from a deleted cell when it finishes
  'reordering'.
- Tell if the table is reordering the cell before I need to
  delete it.

So in short I need to delete a cell that might be reordering from a UITableView.

Have you faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I found a way to do it. Here's the logic just in case anyone ever needs it.

1. Prevent the cell's movement with the use of tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:
2. On delete control don't call [yourTableView].deleteRows, call reloadData

Looks like that's it.
Thanks